# Sync integration between ArcGIS Portal and QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

Currently, I'm using QGIS to handle every data the QGIS is already connected to PostGIS/PostgreSQL.

Now I want to use the data of QGIS to visualize it on ArcGIS Online so I can make dashboards on the QGIS data, and I need the data to be live like every feature added to QGIS will be available on this integration because I'm still use QGIS to edit or add features.

Also I have license of ArcGIS Enterprise so maybe this will help me out.

Comment: Make Query Layers in ArcGIS Pro, symbolize the layers, publish the layers as a service; Done.